# ¿Cómo se llama la figura de la imagen? ¿Tiene vigencia hoy día?

Tags: ortografía

Consultando el NTTLE, en el *Nuevo diccionario enciclopédico ilustrado de la lengua castellana*, por Miguel de Toro y Gómez, de 1901, me encontré cosas como esta:

[image: Definición invadiendo línea inferior]

Me resultó muy curioso el uso de esa especie de llave para ahorrar espacio, haciendo que el final de una definición ocupe la parte desocupada de la siguiente línea. Lo gracioso vino cuando encontré casos en los que lo que se ocupa es la línea anterior:

[image: Definición invadiendo línea superior]

He dicho "llave" pero mi pregunta realmente es ¿cómo se llama esa figura? ¿El hecho de usarla recibía otro nombre diferente? ¿Era de uso común? ¿Sigue vigente hoy día? Si no, ¿cuál fue su ámbito temporal de uso?

Comment: Curioso, en el primer ejemplo parece innecesario ya que tiene su corchete de apertura en `[trumento` pero en el segundo que sube para arriba parece lógico usar algo que lo indique. Especulando yo diría que es un invento improvisado.

Comment: Qué cosa tan curiosa y útil :) Buscando de momento no he encontrado nada relevante, pero sí una referencia para las transcripciones: [Normativa de Transcripción Paleográfica](http://mendezmende.org/es/normativas/transcripcion-paleografica.html)

Comment: Yo recuerdo haberlo usado en el colegio (escribiendo a mano, claro).

Comment: ¡La mar de interesante!  Dos cosas nuevas para mí: la última parte de la línea puesta encima, en vez de debajo, y el corchete grande a la derecha.  Ahora tengo un pequeño proyecto para LaTeX cuando tenga el tiempo (automatizar este proceso, que el paquete `verse` no sabe nada de los corchetes, cosa que me sorprende)

Comment: ¡Es muy interesante! Terminar la palabra arriba o abajo para aprovechar el espacio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RAE: Corchete](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=corchete)

> Signo ortográfico doble (**[ ]**) que se utiliza, por lo general, de forma
>   parecida a los paréntesis que incorporan información complementaria o
>   aclaratoria
>
> [...]
>
> En libros de poesía, se coloca un corchete de
>   apertura delante de las últimas palabras de un verso cuando no se ha
>   transcrito en una sola línea y se termina, alineado a la derecha, en
>   el renglón siguiente:

```
 Y los ritmos indóciles vinieron acercándose,

 juntándose en las sombras, huyéndose y 

                            [buscándose. (Silva Obra [Col. 1880-95])
```

También en las transcripciones como en el comentario de [fedorqui, punto 10](http://mendezmende.org/es/normativas/transcripcion-paleografica.html) (aclarar que el corchete en combinación con otros signos. Es idéntica a la de los paréntesis), denominado [interpolación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolaci%C3%B3n_(filolog%C3%ADa)).

Supongo que los editores habrán utilizado la grafía a modo similar, ¿es posible acceder a una versión anterior del diccionario? Estaría bien ver en las mismas definiciones y para ahorrar costes al modificar esta y otras página añaden la palabra usando el corchete, similar al antiguo uso de las [glosas marginales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glosa) pero sin ocupar el margen.

Comment: He estado buscando, pero no hay ninguna versión anterior de este diccionario.